# How to get SUM and COUNT in the range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have dates in one column, names in the next column and counts in other column.

I want the formula to count the individuals as per the date. 
1. For example, on 11/1/2014, I want Sum of  Kiran's error.
2. For example, on 11/1/2014, I want Count of  Kiran's error.

```
Date    Processed by    Total Errors
11/1/2014   Kiran   1
11/1/2014   Ajay    2
11/1/2014   Kiran   2
11/1/2014   Ajay    1
11/2/2014   Kiran   1
11/2/2014   Ajay    2
11/2/2014   Kiran   2
11/2/2014   Ajay    1
11/3/2014   Kiran   1
11/3/2014   Ajay    2
11/3/2014   Kiran   2
11/3/2014   Ajay    1
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Though you have done a good job of telling us what you want, your question does not tell us what you've tried or researched on your own and where you got stuck. Please read [ask] to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use SUMIFS! Here is an example illustrating what you described below:
[image]

It is not 100% to where you want it but try using the formula that I illustrated. Modify it and learn how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Pivot Tables are for in Excel.

My answer is for Excel 2013:

- Select Insert Tab
- Select Recommended PivotTables to let Excel guess what data you want to see

You will see the first example is exactly what you want:

[image]

[image]